# Delete foreign key referenced table record when setting field to null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am aware when you have a foreign key reference, you can do 'on delete cascade' and if you delete a parent, the child references are deleted as well.

Is there a way to delete the referenced records when the child field is set to null?

```
Place {
  id (PK)
  name
  id_address (FK)
}

Address {
   id (PK)
   name
   city
}
```

I would like the record on address to be deleted if I set place.id_address to null.

Would this be a good case for a trigger? I'd like to to this properly but I'd hate to handle that on the app layer.

Comment: No.  `on delete cascade set null`

Comment: Foreign keys don't work that way. Here, `place` is the child and `address` is the parent: using build-in foreign keys options, you can't delete the parent when a child is modified, it works the other way around.

Comment: This "Is there a way to delete the referenced records when the parent field is set to null?" does not match what you say later: "I would like the record on address to be deleted if I set place.id_address to null." There you are asking for the parent record `Address` to be deleted when the child record in `Place` has `id_address` set to `NULL`. If that is really want then no. That would be dangerous in any case as it would orphan all the other child records.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You are correct, I meant the child. I understand it would be dangerous. What would be the best practice in this case? If I set the place.id_address to null I break the reference, and now I have an orphan address. I would like to automatically delete that orphan. Address and Place have a 1-on-1 relationship so address is not used by any other entity.

Comment: Delete the `Place` record. If by 1-on-1 you mean  a `Address` record can only ever have one `Place` record, then why not merge them into one table?

Comment: It was more of an organizational design, to avoid having merged data that might not be that related but I guess in this case it might make more sense to do so.

Comment: What if other child records reference the same parent entry? Wouldn't the foreign key violated if you set the parent to NULL?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe true in most cases, but here we have a 1-on-1 relationship. The fact we are using two tables it is just to avoid having a huge table and because we wanted the address entity to be separated. So, by setting the place.id_address to null, we are just deleting the address on the place, but now we get an address that we dont use. We dont re use address if that makes it easier to understand. I understand this is more of an app related question but I'd still like to solve this in the DB layer if possible.

Comment: Then why don't you reverse the direction of the foreign key and make it `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think that is a nice clean solution. Do you want to answer so I can award it?

Comment: Before I do that, let me remark that it will only allow to cascade deletes, it won't cascade setting to NULL to a delete. But that's probably what you need for a true 1-to-1 relationship, right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Good point, in this case that is not what we would need. I was thinking on "on delete set null" since that is what we would want. Are we tackling this in a wrong way? Basically we have an address entity, because many things in our database can have an address. We won't re use addresses so no need for 1-to-many. We just dont want to re use city, state, address, etc in multiple tables since they all share the same fields. But, this address is always optional. If you have a better solution, I am all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution for this is a trigger like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION del_addr() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   DELETE FROM address WHERE address.id = OLD.address_id;
   RETURN OLD;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER del_addr AFTER DELETE ON place
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE del_addr();
```